# What Windows app can I use to defragment a FAT32 drive's directories at boot time?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, software-rec, defragment, fat32

What (Windows app) can I use to defragment FAT32 directories?

I used to be a fan of PerfectDisk, but they've disabled the feature in their latest versions, and I have drives that I need to use both in Windows XP/7 and other OSes.

I've checked or tried these ones:

- UltimateDefrag
- UltraDefrag
- JkDefrag/MyDefrag
- PuranDefrag
- Defraggler

None of them handle FAT32 directories. So, what can I use?

Comment: People still use FAT32? :)

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing simpler for an external disk that needs to work on any OS

Comment: By "boot time" do you mean pre-desktop time, i.e. the commandline-like interface that boot-time chkdsk runs from?

Comment: Yes, it's the only moment when directories in FAT32 can be defragmented (the same limitations exist with MFT+etc for NTFS drives)

Comment: You said Defragger, but what about Defraggler?

Comment: Yes, I meant Defraggler... fixed!

Answer (score 1):

IoBit's [Smart Defrag 2](http://www.iobit.com/iobitsmartdefrag.html) has boot time defrag.

Comment: Thanks, I installed it. But it only handles files like 'pagefile.sys'. Directories are not defragmented for FAT32.

Comment: It has an auto defrag feature that defrags during idle time.  It can be turned on for any drive.

Comment: Yes, but since the fragmented directories are spread all over the partition, it doesn't achieve too much. I meant that _at boot-time_, it only handles files like `pagefile.sys`, not the directories, which I'm trying to defragment.

Comment: Since directories can be defragged while Windows is running.  I do not understand why they would need to be defragged at boot time.  There are "Deep Optimize" and "Fast optimize" options when defragging.  Perhaps they can give you the result you are looking for.  Of course if the drive is too full no defragging program is going to work.

Comment: I see that in the latest version "Deep optimize" has been replaced with "Fully Optimize".  I just finished defragging (Fully) my FAT32 thumb drive and it worked well.

Comment: Directories cannot be defragmented for FAT32 drives, unlike NTFS drives where the only files that cannot be defragged "online" are the MFT, metadata, etc. I guess your FAT32 thumb drive just wasn't as fragmented as my external HDD, or you'd seen what I'm talking about.

Comment: User *TheNewbie* is correct, at least for tools using the Windows defragmentation API (most do): *[The Windows defragmentation API refuses to move directories on FAT32 filesystems. This is a known limitation of the Windows defragmentation API.](http://www.mydefrag.com/Manual-KnownProblems.html)*

Answer (score 0):

How about Window's built in Defrag tool?

You can easily set a script to launch it on start.

Comment: Mind putting the contents of that script here?

Answer (score 0):

The only tool compatible with Windows 7 I know of that does this is Paragon Partition Manager Free 2010. (For Windows XP there were more tools supporting FAT32 directory defrag like Norton Speed Disk)

It has to be that version since they removed this feature in the newer versions. You need to hunt that version down using a search engine because it is no longer available on the Paragon homepage.
I use it from time to time to defrag my FAT32 VHDs. It works online (when the drive is not in use) and offline but doesn't use Microsoft's MoveFile API. This means it is potentially more dangerous than Windows' native API. I would recommend a backup before trying.